# remove last inserted element by php in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have container called `interest_type_container`. In which 2 fields are there interest type and period.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="interest_type_container">
    <label class="col-md-4">Interest Type *</label>
    <select name="interest_type[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        // Some options...
    </select>

    <label class="col-md-4">Interest Period *</label>
    <select name="interest_period[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        // Some options...
    </select>
</div>
<button type="button" name="add_more_interest" id="add_more_interest">Add</button>
<button type="button" name="remove_more_interest" id="remove_more_interest">Remove</button>
```

**JQUERY:**
I this I have `add` and `remove` functions. So, when user clicks on add it will add those two fields from `ajax` request.

**AJAX:**

```
$("#add_more_interest").on('click',function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/transaction/fetch_interest_type_and_period',
    success: function (res) {
        $('#interest_type_container').append(res);
    }
});
});
```

And when user clicks on remove. It should remove last inserted 2 fields. I tried with this. But, it's not working.

```
$("#remove_more_interest").on('click', function(){
    $('#interest_type_container:last-child', this).remove();
});
```

Comment: think about it, `:last-child` would only be *the* last child of the parent constainer. You'll have to be much more specific to remove the last two.

Comment: Is the html you are appending organized in some way? Like an <ul>?

Comment: Ehh - are you repeating the ID `interest_type_container`? Also, the selector `$('#interest_type_container:last-child', this)` is trying to find `interest_type_container` as a child of `remove_more_interest` - which isnt the case.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: That's what I am thinking. How can I detect, last inserted elements?

Comment: @tymeJV : those 2 buttons are out of the `div` container.

Comment: @RonakPatel -- I know,.. thats why including `this` in the selector is wrong.

Comment: @tymeJV: ok.. I see.. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your efforts. I come up with a solution. And it works.

Dynamic generated elements, which are coming from `ajax`. I put those elements under `new_inserted_elements` ID.

Now in, **JQUERY:**

```
$("#remove_more_interest").on('click', function(){
    $('#new_inserted_elements').remove();
});
```

It removes last inserted `id`, those are my 2 elements.

Comment: This will give you problems if you keep inserting the same id over and over. ID's are supposed to be unique in pages, so you might want to use a class for this or you'll see odd behavior.

Comment: @JayBlanchard : I am handling this differently in `php`. Still, I can use class instead of id.

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP. If you add elements with the same ID into the DOM you will get weird behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of something you could do given the HTML (pairs of labels and selects with no surrounding element) that you have:

```
$("#remove_more_interest").on('click', function () {
    var labelLength = $('#interest_type_container > label').length - 1;
    var selectLength = $('#interest_type_container > select').length - 1;
    $('#interest_type_container > label').eq(labelLength).remove();
    $('#interest_type_container > label').eq(labelLength - 1).remove();
    $('#interest_type_container > select').eq(selectLength).remove();
    $('#interest_type_container > select').eq(selectLength -1).remove();
});
```

This is using straight up brute force though, there may be better, more elegant ways to accomplish this.
http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/uohc23xd/

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem. It's removing textboxes and not labels. One more thing, when you keep pressing remove button, it removes other HTML elements from `DOM` too.

Comment: In the example provided it works fine, is it not working in your code? I would have to see more of your markup to make the selector corrections necessary to customize this for your HTML.

Comment: I made it more specific @RonakPatel

Comment: Thanks for your support. I come up with new solution. I am posting it. And it works perfect according to requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the tag type and use "last" selector

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove_more_interest', function(){
    $('#interest_type_container').children('label:last').remove();
    $('#interest_type_container').children('select:last').remove();
});
```

You can test your selector from your web browser console by hitting F12 and select console tab. Wrote these lines and you'll see what it returns. This Console is your best friend!

**Your onclick method is not good! The complete code HERE**

```
<html><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#remove_more_interest', function(){
    $('#interest_type_container').children('label:last').remove();
    $('#interest_type_container').children('select:last').remove();
    $('#interest_type_container').children('label:last').remove();
    $('#interest_type_container').children('select:last').remove();
});
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="interest_type_container">
    <label class="col-md-4">Interest Type *</label>
    <select name="interest_type[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>

    <label class="col-md-4">Interest Period *</label>
    <select name="interest_period[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button type="button" name="remove_more_interest" id="remove_more_interest">Remove</button>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Why is his click method not good? `#remove_more_interest` exists when jQuery runs, so the event is bound properly.

Comment: Run my code and after, test it with his onclick .... It doesn't works! You should use this onclick method for generated HTML code! @Ronak Patel

Comment: I run the code in the fiddle that I provided as an example and it works just fine. Event delegation does not apply here, The problem in his original code is how he specified `:last-child`, not the click event handler.

Comment: He will get problems when dom is not generated, this way is more safe! Your code works too, but mine is doign the same with 4 lines in less @JayBlanchard

Comment: Safe? It has nothing to do with safety. Yes - your code is shorter (now that you have edited it) but it has nothing to do with event delegation. Your code is also missing the important fact that 2 selects and 2 labels have to be removed. The OP adds these labels and selects as pairs @BigPino

Comment: Safety is making you better. Sorry for missunderstanding his question, english is not my first language. Just double the remove part. The best way to pair Label with input is the label tag "for" which is associted with input ID. And grab the label like this `$('label[for="YOUR_INPUT_ID"]')` @JayBlanchard

Comment: I think our both solution are good and needs to be upvoted @JayBlanchard

Comment: I would upvote yours, but it doesn't answer the OP's question about removing the matched sets of labels and selects.

Comment: Your code fails when more than one set is added. It removes all labels and selects - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5uh6ctzg/

Comment: If you give the same name to your inputs, you search for problems and is a bad practice, give them different names @JayBlanchard or match it with IDs instead of names. Do not be in bad faith!

Comment: Not in bad faith @BigPino, just testing the code as you have it written. Inputs have the same name *all of the time* and so we have to account for that.

Comment: You've add second times the both set of label and select @JayBlanchard. It's not as I wrote IT. Come on! And what about IDs which is should be unique?

Comment: Neither the label or the select elements have id's on them. I copied and pasted your exact code into the fiddle and then copied and pasted the label and select as you have them into your code. It doesn't work.

Comment: When you want a label bound to an input, you are suppose to use the label tage "for". This is the clean method !! http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Comment: Keep in mind that the OP *is adding these elements*, that is why he was looking for an answer @BigPino.

Comment: Label can be applied in many different ways, the OP's way is still valid HTML.

Comment: What do you call OP ?

Comment: After reviewing your code @JayBlanchard, i rollback my solution to a previous revision which is the same as you propose but written in other way. I don't know why you are so argumentative.

Comment: Or this line clear every child `$('#interest_type_container').children().remove()`

Comment: I'm not the one being argumentative honestly. I am just pointing out that the code you supplied doesn't work for the conditions that the OP (original poster) setup. Now with your edits it does work as the OP would hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. When you append the result, put it in a container e.g.

```
    $('#interest_type_container').append('<span class="appended_res">'+res+'</span>');
```

After that, you can use class 'appended_res' to remove the elements.

Comment: Sometimes, '("#selector").on("event")' doesn't work for dynamically generated DOM, whereas '(document).on("event", "#selector")' works.

Comment: Since he is binding to something that exists at the time jQuery runs ( `#remove_more_interest` ) event delegation is not necessary.

Comment: Hmmm, I see that '("#remove_more_interest")' is already loaded and doesn't come after ajax request so 2nd part of my answer is not necessary in this case.

Comment: I have removed it from my answer now.